# Composer BaseIO hasAuthentication compatibility error with Composer IOInterface hasAuthentication

Tags: composer-php

Getting the following error message when calling composer install.

Fatal error: Declaration of Composer\IO\BaseIO::hasAuthentication($repositoryName) must be compatible with Composer\IO\IOInterface::hasAuthentication(string $repositoryName) in phar:///usr/local/psa/var/modules/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/IO/BaseIO.php on line 20

This is occurring in our dev environment when we run the gitlab pipeline to build and deploy in our CI/CD pipeline. No changes have been made to this process that has been running flawlessly for years. My guess is that something has changed in the composer base code library in the last few days.

Anyone else having this same issue? Or does anyone have a clue on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please share more details. Which version of Composer do you use? If this is a pretty recent one, please report this as a bug in Composer's issue tracker

Comment: [Composer in Alpine Docker PHP Fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71763820/1426539)