# Composer in Alpine Docker PHP Fatal error

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

**UPDATE: php-curl extension was causing Segmentation Fault.**

I am running docker pipelines with alpine 3.15 and PHP 7.0 and 7.1 on an ARM64.

I install composer using

```
COPY --from=composer:latest  /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

Since yesterday, 5th of April, all pipelines fail with the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Composer\IO\BaseIO::hasAuthentication($repositoryName) must be compatible with Composer\IO\IOInterface::hasAuthentication(string $repositoryName) in phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/IO/BaseIO.php on line 20

I tried using older versions of composer, but on all them I get:

> Segmentation fault

This was working fine for the past 6 months. So something changed recently on the composer builds.
I also tried running on Intel and to install the composer the classical way, however, I also get the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are installing `composer:latest`, which as of today will install Composer 2.3. And you are doing it on PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1.

Those PHP versions [are no longer supported by Composer 2.3](https://blog.packagist.com/composer-2-3/) (nor by PHP, for what it's worth).

> As announced in the 2.2 release notes, Composer 2.3 increases the required PHP version to >=7.2.5 and thus stops supporting PHP 5.3.2 - 7.2.4. The 2.2 LTS is still there for users stuck on older PHP versions.

Your options are:

- Upgrade PHP so use something supported. If you **have** to remain in v7, you can at least upgrade to PHP 7.4
- Use an older version of composer. Instead of an unconstrained "latest" tag, point to a specific one you know it's supported.

You can try with version 2.2, which I think should work. If not, keep going backwards until you find one that works with your stack.

```
COPY --from=composer:2.2  /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

---

This **WON'T** work:

```
FROM php:7.1-cli-alpine

COPY --from=composer:2.3  /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN mkdir /someproject
WORKDIR /someproject

RUN composer create-project symfony/skeleton .
```

But this **will**:

```
FROM php:7.1-cli-alpine

COPY --from=composer:2.2  /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN mkdir /someproject
WORKDIR /someproject

RUN composer create-project symfony/skeleton .
```

Comment: Thanks, but all older versions do not work either. I get Segmentation faults on all of them which are older than 2.2. The newer ones cannot be used due to php versions.

Comment: The error you report is because of what I mention here: You are using a too old version of PHP. That simply won't work. If you can't upgrade PHP (which you should), you won't be able to use composer v2.3+

Comment: LE: seems I can install composer 2.2, however, I get a segmentation fault when running composer install on the actual Laravel installation. However, it works if I use composer outside the root folder. That is weird..

Comment: I take that back. Segmentation fault everywhere.

Comment: Unless I see the exact image you are using, I won't be able to reproduce the issue. I've used both 2.2 and 2.3 and didn't get a "segmentation fault" error, so I'd need more details to be able to see what's going on. Check if you can provide the `Dockerfile` you are using. Or better yet, a minimal `Dockerfile` that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Also, we'd need to see the full error message, not just "segmentation fault". We need to see where exactly does it come up.

Comment: Sure.

https://github.com/allexivan/composer-debug

 Error message:

`#29 [php_install 10/13] RUN  cd /var/www/html && composer install
#29 sha256:5f708a0d183a150e874ba5adf82ef94f110db16ff20354aa965b38acba056f1b
#29 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd $GIT_PATH && composer install]: exit code: 139
------
 > [php_install 10/13] RUN  cd /var/www/html && composer install:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd $GIT_PATH && composer install]: exit code: 139`

If I run composer install in the docker shell, I just get:

`Segmentation fault`

Same on ARM or intel

Comment: Sorry, that Dockerfile is not minimal enough to find out where the error is. There is no way I can run that and debug it to see where your issue is. But I can easily demonstrate that composer 2.2 works with PHP7.1, whereas composer 2.3 does not. [This Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/r2EUf0z8) won't build, but [this one](https://pastebin.com/rbKu6bw1) will.

Comment: You'll need to work your way until you find what's exactly causing your issue for your particular build. But PHP 7.1 and Composer 2.2, as demonstrated above, should generally work.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I found the issue for my case. it was caused by the php-curl extension. When uninstalled, composer worked without any segmentation faults.
Now I need to check why it is causing this.